# how to use spectrogram with 2D array in python?

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, accelerometer, spectrogram

need to modify the following code to create a spectrogram

```
column_names = ['user-id','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
data = pd.read_csv('filepath',delimiter='\t')
```

and this is a sample of the data:

```
33  2   4.91E+13    -0.6946377  12.680544   0.50395286
33  2   4.91E+13    5.012288    11.264028   0.95342433
33  2   4.91E+13    4.903325    10.882658   -0.08172209
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately, NO!